# Need Github ".gitignore" file after creating repository without adding it

Tags: git, github, reference, repository, gitignore

I have created my repository but forgot to add the already provided .gitignore files which github propose at the creation moment.

So i want to know how can i find those awesome files and add them to my repo after creating it??

Any other good reference, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options available:

1. The original collection of .gitignore file templates, [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/).
2. A good website which you can Create useful ".gitignore" files for your project based on Operating Systems, IDEs, or Programming Languages. [Here](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore) you go.